# SCP for magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, price

I need SCP for magento 1.9.2.4 like this https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this Extension working in 1.9 you need to change some line

steps shown below url

http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/

and also move file From base/default to your theme this things work for me 1.9.2.1 and also work in 1.9.2.4

Please try and let me know

Comment: I tryed it and work.  But now have a new issue, after I installed SCP, the simple product with options shows zero price when select an option.

Comment: Can you show me  screenshot or something

Comment: Hi, look this video on site test with SCP.  This is a simple product with options https://app.hyfy.io/v/abb3SFBAy7/

Comment: Add to cart product and check what price is coming for that product , is it right

Comment: Hi, It shows the price in cart: https://app.hyfy.io/v/abQoSYmzy7/

Comment: Its working on my default rwd theme , may be some issue with your theme , I suggest try to write your own js code instead.

Comment: But, it is coming after installation SCP on site test... The live site work fine and live site haven't SCP.
look live site: https://app.hyfy.io/v/abcqOxJQy7/

Comment: replace your price.phtml with rwd price.phtml and try agian

Comment: And if your js is merged then unmerged your js and clear cache and try again

Comment: Hi, I solved...the problem is in scpoptions.phtml file  line 98 and 117.  

under customtemplate/template/catalog/product/view/scpoptions.phtml  ... add .price in this mode:

line 98: price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()].price);

line 117: price += parseFloat(this.config[optionId][selectOption.value].price);